# How to hack css Inline style only on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How to hack css Inline style only on IE ?

to hack css Inline style only on IE in all version, How can i do ?

Like that

```
<div style = "
               color: #eee;
               border: 1px solid #000;
for ie only // line-height : 32px;     
             "/>
```

Comment: This question is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750088/css-display-inline-block-issue-with-ie

Comment: @ViniciusMonteiro thats IE6/7 only

Comment: When asking questions like this, please always specify the IE version(s) that you need it to work for. Also, please elaborate on what the problem is in IE that you're trying to fix; there might be an alternative solution that doesn't require IE hacks.

Comment: @JochemQuery This question covers all versions of IE, I tested to make sure.

Comment: Here is an extensive list of css hacks you can use both inline and in separate stylesheet http://abbasharoon.me/css-hacks-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `*` before the property name, and that will target only IE7, so you need to write this `line-height : 32px;` as `*line-height : 32px;`

As I realized you wanted hacks for each IE, so here you go

- For IE6 - `_`
- For IE7 - `*`
- For IE8 - `\0`
- For IE9 - `\9`

---

Declare styles for IE10 specifically using CSS Only

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
   /* This won't go inline but can be used at document level*/
   /* Declaration Blocks Goes Here*/
}
```

You can read [here](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/) for more information on how to declare IE only styles using `@media` queries

---

Still I would suggest you to use conditional comments which will make your life much easier instead of declaring inline styles.

Comment: and ie 8,9,10 how can i do ?

Comment: OP asks for all IE versions, why would you give IE7 specific advise?

Comment: @JochemQuery I really don't know how I answered only IE7, I guess time to sleep now

Comment: strange I thought this question was about IE7 only as well somehow

Comment: Nice edit, but I still would advise OP to not use inline css for so much rules. Would make a mess of it, not saying that it isnt a good answer

Comment: i use `^line-height : 32px;` but work on ie7 only

how to use in ie8,9,10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    div.classname{
        line-height: 32px; //ie only 
    }
<![endif]-->
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Edit:

- Give that div a class
- Give that class a specific ie style.

Comment: i want to use css Inline

Comment: @user3215821 why is that? any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   #myElement {
        /* Enter your style code */
   }
}
```