# how to add style css only on ie8 using inline css?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

How to add style css only on ie8 using inline css ?

I tried to use this code but not work.

```
<div style="width: 100%; *width: 1263px;"></div>
```

I test on ie8, but i show only `width: 100%;`

How to get `width: 1263px;` only on ie8 ?

Comment: Not sure you can... What about conditional comments?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search: this [How to hack css Inline style only on IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238767/how-to-hack-css-inline-style-only-on-ie) question it seems as though you can try the following:

- For IE6 _
- For IE7 *
- For IE8 \0
- For IE9 \9