# How to center container with unknown width and floated elements inside on fluid page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know there are lots of ways to center content with an unknown width on a fluid width page in HTML/CSS but I can't get them to work in this case for some reason and need help.

Firstly, let me state that I need a solution that works in common browsers and in IE6 (don't ask why).

Here's an example of markup and the problem. In this example I want the yellow boxes centered inside the blue box.

[example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/7U7Ya/2/)

```
<div style="background:blue;margin:0 auto;width:100%;">
    <table style="margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
                <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried this method using a table but I also tried the -50% +50% method. I am happy to use any method that works on all common browsers and IE6.

Can someone help me fix it.

Please do not lecture me on IE6 or incorrect use of the TABLE tag.

Comment: see this john http://jsfiddle.net/rs5An/ . you can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left;`

Comment: @Beginner: thanks but inline-block not supported in IE6/7.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750088/css-display-inline-block-issue-with-ie . it will sove your ie issues...

Comment: I would prefer not to use these IE6 hacks. Surely this is possible with floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research I can find no solution to this that works in all browsers and doesn't require IE6 hacks.

The best solution is display:inline-block and IE6/7 and various other hacks (eg. FF2).

The final solution taken from [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) is as follows:

```
<style>
    li {
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 5px;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        _height: 250px;
    }
</style>

<li>
        <div>
            <h4>This is awesome</h4>
            <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg"
            alt="lobster" width="75" height="75"/>
        </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="width: 379px;">
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
            <div style="background:yellow;float:left;padding:50px;">Test</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: My apologies. In my question I didn't mention that it needs to work on a fluid width page. I updated my example and removed the fixed width.

Comment: Checked the jsfiddle... The yellow area needs to be centered in the blue area, regardless of page width.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't click update, updated now, yellow divs centered in any width except width lower then 378px and will show scroll bar (size of yellow div is fixed). http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/7U7Ya/6/

Comment: I can't use a fixed width for the blue area. Depending on page width only one yellow block may fit per line, or it might be 10 or more.

Answer (score 0):

what I understood from your requirement that you want to make your div to center ? then please have a look on the below code

```
<style type="text/css">

.yourclass
{
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    padding:50px;
}
.blueback
{
    background:blue;    
}
.mytable
{
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;       
}
div.clear
{
   clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="blueback">
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
            <div class="yourclass">Test</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I cannot use a fixed width like you have on .blueback as this is on a fluid width page.

Comment: hi john I have edited my code now check and let me know

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't do what I need because there is only a maximum of 3 yellow boxes per line. I need it to be fluid so there could be 1 yellow box or there could be 10 or more.